# Does $|f\sin (x)|$ integrable on $\mathbb{R}$ imply that $|f|$ integrable on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: fourier-analysis, characteristic-functions

I guess not. Because we usually require $|f|$ to be integrable on ℝ so that it has the fourier transform.

Can anyone give me an counterexample for the statement in the title? I have searched for quite a while but still haven't  got an counterexample.

I am actually trying to find the necessary and sufficient condition so that the following equality holds.
$$F(b)−F(a)=\int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{e^{−iat}−e^{−ibt}}{it}\phi (t)dt,\forall a,b \in \mathbb{R} $$
where $F$ is the cumulative distribution function of a random variable $X$ and $\phi$ is the characteristic function of $X$. The integral is in the Lebesgue sense.

I found that $\frac{e^{−iat}−e^{−ibt}}{it}\phi(t)$ integrable for all $a,b$ and $X$ does not have point mass would be a necessary and sufficient condition. But it is hard to check $\frac{e^{−iat}−e^{−ibt}}{it}\phi(t)$ integrable for all $a,b$.

Since it is not hard to see that $\int_{[T,∞)∪(−∞,−T]}|\phi(t)|/|t|dt<∞ $for some $T>0$ would imply that $\frac{e^{−iat}−e^{−ibt}}{it}\phi(t)$ integrable for all $a,b$. By taking $a=−1,b=1, \frac{e^{−iat}−e^{−ibt}}{it}\phi(t)$ integrable for all $a,b$ implies $2\sin(t)\phi(t)/t$ integrable and then I am wondering whether the statement in the title is true.

Comment: How about $\sin x/x,$ multiplied by a bump function if you want integrability over the whole line?

Comment: @KevinCarlson， Thanks！you mean  $f(x)=\frac{\sin(x)e^{-\frac{1}{1-x^2}}}{x} 1_{\{|x|\leq 1\}}$ where $1$ is the indicator function?

Comment: In the definition of $f$, you should drop the $\sin$ factor, otherwise it is a fine example. You could also drop the $e^{\dots}$ factor to make the example easier.

Comment: @PhoemueX, I see...It seems to be much easier than I think... Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

As commenters said, the answer is negative: e.g.,  $f(x) =|x|^{-1} e^{-|x|}$  is a nonintegrable function such that $|f(x)\sin x|$ is globally integrable.

More generally, the following are equivalent:

1. $f$ is integrable whenever  $fg$ is;
2. $\operatorname{ess\,inf}|g|>0$

Indeed, if 2) fails then the sets $A_n = \{x:  2^{-n}\le |g(x)|<2^{1-n}\}$ have positive measure for infinitely many $A_n$. Restrict attention to only such $n$ and pick a  subset $B_n\subset A_n$ of finite positive measure for each of them. Then the function
$$
f(x) = \sum_n  |B_n|^{-1} \chi_{B_n}
$$
is not integrable, but $fg$ is. $\quad\Box$

The implication $2) \implies 1)$ is easy.